# get the completed object (including parent, grandparent) in a deeply nested JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a nested JSON and it looks like below. When I am on a page, I search the JSON for the page link and if the flag is true, I want to return the complete object

```
"pages": [
{
    "link": "sample.html",
    "flag": false,
    "child1": [],
    
},
{
    "link": "sample2.html",
    "flag": false,
    "child1": [
        {
            "link": "sample2a.html",
            "child2": []
        }
    ],
},
{
    "link": "sample3.html",
    "flag": true,
    "child1": [
        {
            "link": "sample3a.html",
            "child2": [
                {
                    "link": "sample3a1.html",
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3a2.html"
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3a3.html"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "link": "sample3b.html",
            "child2": [
                {
                    "link": "sample3b1.html",
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3b2.html"
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3b3.html"
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
]
```

For eg. If I am on **sample3a2.html** page and if the flag is true, it should return me the complete object as below.

I have tried this with recursive function but not able to get the complete object, it just returns the current level it is on.

```
{
    "link": "sample3.html",
    "flag": true,
    "child1": [
        {
            "link": "sample3a.html",
            "child2": [
                {
                    "link": "sample3a1.html",
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3a2.html"
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3a3.html"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "link": "sample3b.html",
            "child2": [
                {
                    "link": "sample3b1.html",
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3b2.html"
                },
                {
                    "link": "sample3b3.html"
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
```

Code that I tried

```js
function checkFlag(pages, currentPageUrl) {
  function searchInObject(obj) {
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
      if (obj.link === currentPageUrl) {
        console.log("obj.link", obj)
        return obj;
      }
      for (const key in obj) {
        const result = searchInObject(obj[key]);
        if (result !== undefined) {
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  }
  for (const page of pages) {
    const result = searchInObject(page);
    if (result !== undefined) {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
let currentURL = "sample3a2.html"
checkFlag(pages, currentURL)
```

```html
<script>
  const pages = [{
      "link": "sample.html",
      "flag": true,
      "child1": [],

    },
    {
      "link": "sample2.html",
      "flag": false,
      "child1": [{
        "link": "sample2a.html",
        "child2": []
      }],
    },
    {
      "link": "sample3.html",
      "flag": true,
      "child1": [{
          "link": "sample3a.html",
          "child2": [{
              "link": "sample3a1.html",
            },
            {
              "link": "sample3a2.html"
            },
            {
              "link": "sample3a3.html"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "link": "sample3b.html",
          "child2": [{
              "link": "sample3b1.html",
            },
            {
              "link": "sample3b2.html"
            },
            {
              "link": "sample3b3.html"
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Valid JSON doesn't start with `"pages":` Please add the braces.

Comment: I made you a snippet, there was a non-printable character in the JavaScript

Comment: @trincot they likely have a larger object but call the script with `object.pages` or something, just simplified here

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the JSON, it is just a part of the huge json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the page instead of result like below code:

```
for (const page of pages) {  
    const result = searchInObject(page);
    if (result !== undefined) {
    console.log("obj.link", page) 
      return page;     // change here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it did not strike me. This is working